# Requesting resource failed because it is complex

Tags: java, android, android-logcat, r.java-file

I am getting a warning in the logcat each time running the app.

```
Requesting resource 0x7f0b008c failed because it is complex
```

I checked this resource in R.java, its the custome theme I applied. The application works perfectly, I just want to know that does this warning make any problems in future.

**Complete logcat**

```
11-25 20:02:22.080: W/ResourceType(7403): Requesting resource 0x7f0b008d failed because it is      complex
11-25 20:02:22.090: W/PackageManager(7403): Failure retrieving text 0x7f0b008d in package com.chiron.astrotest
11-25 20:02:22.090: W/PackageManager(7403): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0b008d
11-25 20:02:22.090: W/PackageManager(7403):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
11-25 20:02:22.090: W/PackageManager(7403):     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1007)
11-25 20:02:22.090: W/PackageManager(7403):     at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadLabel(ComponentInfo.java:85)
11-25 20:02:22.090: W/PackageManager(7403):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
11-25 20:02:22.090: W/PackageManager(7403):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
11-25 20:02:22.090: W/PackageManager(7403):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
11-25 20:02:22.090: W/PackageManager(7403):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
11-25 20:02:22.090: W/PackageManager(7403):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-25 20:02:22.090: W/PackageManager(7403):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-25 20:02:22.090: W/PackageManager(7403):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
11-25 20:02:22.090: W/PackageManager(7403):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 20:02:22.090: W/PackageManager(7403):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-25 20:02:22.090: W/PackageManager(7403):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
11-25 20:02:22.090: W/PackageManager(7403):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
11-25 20:02:22.090: W/PackageManager(7403):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you share your code here?

Comment: Which code do you want??

Comment: complete logcat updated